# AJAX not working on MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am using MVC3 with Razor. I have one Action which want to load using AJAX. I am using jQuery UIblock plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/block/# to show some wait image to user.

The View corresponding to action is as shown below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnBegin = "BlockUI", OnComplete = "UnBlockUI", UpdateTargetId = "page" }))
{
...................
}
```

Javascript code is as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BlockUI() {
    $.blockUI({ message: "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")' />" });
}

function UnBlockUI() {
    $.unblockUI({ message: "Done....." });
}
```

Now I am redirecting to Action using a link as

```
location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Search/")';
```

When the search view is loading, I cannot see any Div showing Loading image.

The same thing is working on other page, the only difference is that on other pages the Image is coming on **POSTBACK**.

Additionally, all Ajax **POST** operations are working but not **GET** ones.

What is the problem with Search page here ??

Thanks.

Comment: your ajax `get` operations are not working because you, most likely, don't have an action method that accepts `get` requests ... post the `signature`s of the applicable controller actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I am redirecting to Action using a link as
>
> location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Home/Search/")';

The keyword here is *I am redirecting*. It's not *I am sending an AJAX request*. When you redirect, the browser simply stops running any scripts on the current page and redirects away to the target location. The `OnBegin` and `OnComplete` methods that you have subscribed to will never fire when you redirect which is why you are not seeing any blockUI.

Comment: Thanks Darin for the clarification. But then If I want Ajax request on click of an link what should i do ??

Comment: You could use an `Ajax.ActionLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`.

Comment: I am using Jquery to navigate to other page. So can't use Ajax.ActionLink and Html.ActionLink.

Comment: You could use ajax with jquery then.